# Build .tabbable without the .tab-pane id attribute

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to build the following omitting the id attributes (not using js)?

```
<div class="tabbable">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Existing TLDs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">New TLDs</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active fade in" id="tab1">
      <p>I'm in Section 1.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="tab2">
      <p>I'm in Section 2.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm quite grumpy when it comes to assigning id to an element (especially a non-container).

Answer (score 1):

The docs say, "Tab should have either a data-target or an href targeting a container node in the DOM."

If these were just links in a non-bootstrap html page - how else could we href another unique element on the page?  That's what the id is for.  It can be done either with a descriptive id or with JS (dynamically assigning id1, id2, etc), but we have to use one or the other.

My 2 cents: using id's feel cleaner to me at first than "data-toggle", and they don't have to clutter things... I would prefer describing the section, like 'home' & 'about'.

However, when the number/names of the tabs grow/change, I sometimes use 'tab1' and 'tab2' if assigning on the fly with js or server-side.  Not to rant here, but I think it's also noteworthy that alot of the bootstrap examples use that "id1", "id2" syntax, which leads people to think hardcoding it that way is normal/correct/ok... which can lead to some pretty messy code...  When in fact, I think most CLASSES (nav-fixed-top, spanX, etc) are likely to change, and are all truly intended to be assigned dynamically (via JS or less).  I wish that were explained on the first page of the docs.  Once you embrace the entire toolbox, - it really is powerful.

Sorry to rant, I hope that's helpful!

Comment: Man, instead of helping me out, you pointed out a good point of why IDs are useful approach. Which I totally agree with(therefore upping your answer), but up to a point where you start looking in an a bit more serious webapp: tabs inside tabs inside tabs inside list items inside tabs.. In such case, assigning IDs to those elements means wasting namespaces like crazy. You gotta feel the danger there. So, I insisted on no-js approach because there already are some components that support selectors in data-target attribute(ex: navbar). I'd like the same for tabs.

Comment: Hmm, the responsive navbar uses the collapse.js plugin, and it's data-target still needs an id, is that correct?

Comment: Nope, just a plain ol selector, class being enough.

Comment: Class will work, but wouldn't they always have to be unique for a data-target to select them? If we have multiple tabs, they need to know which div to target... so we could use $.closest() or something like that... the only other thing I can think of is not "bootstrap" but maybe this will help: http://www.jotform.org/css3/pure-css-tab-navigation-menu/#more-373